# Difference b/w getting output to array in bash using `command` vs ($(command))

Tags: bash, unix

What is difference b/w these two command and output variable:

```
output=($(command))
```

And

```
output=`command`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, the resulting variable is an array, with the number of elements depending on the output of your command. In the second case, it is a scalar containing the complete result value. This difference is only due to the extra outer brackets in the first case.

Try it with, for example, the `ls` command to see the difference.

Additionally, the `$(command)` form has superseded the `'command'` form for command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that `$()` calls can be nested, AFAIR (okay, backticks can be nested too, but you have to escape all nested backticks, so `$()` provides nicer syntax).